# How to list the recent files, when open neovim when no file is assigned

Tags: neovim

I wish to realize something like this:

> When open nvim with command `nvim`, it lists the recent files waiting for choose.
> and open nvim with `nvim XXX`, it does not list the recent files, just opens XXX.

I installed [vim-fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim.git), thus command `:History` will list the recent files.

I tried to add `autocmd BufNewFile  :History` into my vimrc. However, it does not work.
Also I tried `autocmd BufNewFile *.vim :History`, when open run `nvim a.vim`, the files lists. However, dislike open it by run `:History` in an existing nvim interface, the listed files does not be able to be choosed.